# Rescrict Ip's per Pc/Server

Tags: networking, router, ip, home-networking, switch

I am faily new to networking and want to lern more about it.

Lets say i have 2 Servers and give each one a specific ip

server 1 has 192.168.178.10

server 2 has 192.168.178.11

and here is my problem:

I want server 1 and server 2 to only have use their assigned ip's and prevent them from using any other ip.

so Server 1 can't use 192.168.178.11
and Server 2 can't use 192.168.178.10

what type of equipment is needed to prevent the unwanted access of other ips?

How do i need to setup my network to allow specific ip ranges for different machines and prevent them from using any other ip?

and how is the method called to do this so i can learn more about it

i've read about pfsense and that they can route different ips to different macs but you can also spoof and change those macs and access get their ips

best regards

Justin

Comment: Your router should support static IP assignments

Comment: What is the exact problem you are trying to solve? Do you not trust the administrators of your servers not to change the IP adress or are you afraid your servers will be compromised? How are your servers connected to the network? Do they share a switch or are they connected to the same router? Do you have any means to separate these servers from the rest of the network to prevent them from using each other's IP adress, for example using a firewall or an (advanced) layer-3 switch?

Comment: its more like a server rack in a datacentre but i want to test ist in home networking first. i dont have any epuipment yet

Comment: i just want to split one subnet "/27" and assign is to different servers so they can only have specified ips and cant use any other ips